# Application fails to start when additional port is opened through an autoconfig as a module

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I am trying to create a library which can enable exposing a SpringBoot app on a second port (8090).

For this to work I have an AutoConfiguration as defined below:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(
    type = Type.SERVLET
)
public class HttpConfig {
    public HttpConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(new Connector[]{this.createStanderConnecter()});
        return factory;
    }

    private Connector createStanderConnecter() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setPort(8090);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

If I define this configuration in the same project, it works just fine.
But if I import this config as a module, my application fails to start with following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to multiple ServletWebServerFactory beans : tomcatServletWebServerFactory,servletContainer
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I figured. If someone else wants to accomplish what I am trying to do. Instead of the configuration, I had to implement `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` as follows:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(
    type = Type.SERVLET
)
public class HttpConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public HttpConfig() {
    }

    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(new Connector[]{this.createStanderConnecter()});
    }

    private Connector createStanderConnecter() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setPort(8090);
        return connector;
    }
}
```